# The "$" - who had it first? jQuery or browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am wondering where the `$` (dollar sign) is coming from. I noticed that all major browsers support the $ a synonym for `document.querySelector`.

Now, is that something that jQuery as inspired the browsers to do? Is there a specification for it?

Or has it been there before jQuery was a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noticed that all major browsers support the $ a synonym for document.querySelector.

*Browsers* don't. Developer Tools Consoles do … and jQuery predates those by years.

People were using `$()` as a wrapper around `document.getElementById` long before jQuery cane onto the scene though.

Comment: Of course, I was referring to the devtools. Thanks a lot, that's the answer I was looking for.